# Trigger a animation from view outside

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make an animation view, it will rotate when clicked.

like this:

```
struct AnimatedView: View {
    
    @State var degree: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("picture")
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(degree))
                .animation(
                    Animation.linear(duration: 2)
            )
            Button(action: {
                self.degree = 180.0
            }) {
                Text("animate").frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func active() {
        self.degree = 180.0
    }
}
```

I place this view in ContentView, and I want to active the animation from other button not in the view.

I found function **active** can't change **degree** value, so the animation not start.

I knew use @Blinding keep degree variable in ContentView may work, but I don't like too much variable in there.

Comment: Would you show on which condition/case in ContentView you want to activate animation in this view?

Comment: Just for... prepare future features? I want design a view just use simple function active/disable to use, not need handle it's variable.

Comment: SwifUI is reactive by nature. So then just create paired view model for AnimatedView and make that effect to be activated by some published property in view model.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you need to use a `@Binding`, i.e.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var degree: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AnimatedView(degree: $degree)
            Button(action: {
                self.degree += 180.0
            }) {
                Text("animate")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedView: View {
    @Binding var degree: Double

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(degree))
            .animation(
                Animation.linear(duration: 2)
            )
    }
}
```